# cannot fetch the data from firebase database in react native

Tags: react-native

Hereby I did all the methods of getting the data I got them for one time after refers my screen the data will not come

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

import { db } from './config';

let itemsRef = db.ref('/faculty/1');

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#ebebeb'
    }
});

export default class List extends Component {
    state = {
        items: []
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        itemsRef.on('value', snapshot => {
            let data = snapshot.val()
            console.log(data)
            let items = Object.values(data);
            //self.setState({ items: items });
            console.log("data",items);
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                {this.state.items.length > 0 ? (
                    <ItemComponent items={this.state.items} />
                ) : (
                    <Text>no data</Text>
                )}
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

whats is a mistake for getting the data please tell me

this is the data

[image]

Comment: Technically you are setting the items in the state. Uncomment this line self.setState({ items: items });  and try.

Comment: i tried but the data console did print any values

Comment: Then start with itemsRef and see if it has any data

Comment: i tried the data will not come if its any change i make in the firebase project

Comment: It is hard to tell with the code that you posted. Start with your db component. Are you able to establish the connection with db successfully? Did you debug and check if your db config is ok and fetching data as it should be without any errors?

Comment: if its any changes in rules